# Init github repository

Tags: git, github

I've just created a new Github repository, but apparently forgot to allow Github to create the README and so on with which it helpfully offers to initialize the repository.

I attempted to create this locally and push it with the following commands:

```
git remote add origin
git push -u origin master
```

However, it keeps giving me the error:

`https://github.com/Arkaaito/<repo>/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

I don't know how to run git update-server-info on Github because Github does not provide shell access via ssh; there's got to be some UI option for it somewhere, but I don't know where.  Can anyone help me find the blindingly obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post the result of `git remote show origin` From the looks of the error you got, you simply forgot to include the repo name after your username...

Also, the error is mentioned on [this GitHub help article](https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors) as the result of using a really old version of git or not having push access to a repo.  (It can also be the result of an incorrect remote origin URL, for instance a URL with incorrect capitalization.)

**EDIT**: Just noticed that it was the formatting that made `<repo>` appear blank, it's most likely that you just have an older version of git, so update.

Comment: Updating my git version didn't help, but the link you sent also suggested checking the *case* of the URL set for the remote origin.  Sure enough, I was capitalizing my project name, but apparently it was really supposed to be lowercase.  I've edited the answer slightly to call out that possibility from the linked help article as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a repo on Github.
2. Create a repo on your local machine:

   ```
   $ cd Foo  
   $ touch README.md  
   $ git init  
   $ git add .
   $ git commit -m "Initial commit"
   ```
3. Link your repo between local & remote, then push to remote:

   ```
   $ git remote add origin git@github.com:<your_username>/Foo.git
   $ git push -u origin master
   ```

If you get a conflict then, pull from remote repo before push:

```
$ git pull
```